# SQL/Hive: Finding total number of users in a room when a user first joins a room

Tags: sql, hive

Data preview:

```
user room start_time leave_time 
  a1    A     07:44      08:02   
  b2    A     07:45      07:50
  c3    A     07:49      08:05 
  d4    A     08:03      08:05
```

Is there a way to add a column called 'total_num_user' counting total number of users in a room when each person first joined the room?

Desired output:

```
user room start_time leave_time total_num_user 
  a1    A     07:44      08:02         1
  b2    A     07:45      07:50         2
  c3    A     07:49      08:05         3
  d4    A     08:03      08:05         2
```

I tried writing a pseudocode that count when start_time of other user < start_time of user and end_time of other user > end_time of user group by room, but stuck on how to actually implement this in SQL.

Comment: Could you please explain more precise the logic behind that column? I don't understand why the number for user d4 should be 2. To me, either the number 4 would make sense or the number 1, but why 2?

Comment: @JonasMetzler Yes, sorry there was a typo in second data preview: the reason why d4 is 2 is because by the time d4 entered the room, c3 and d4 are the only ones in a room.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more than you wanted

```
create table timeTable (username varchar(10), room varchar(10),start_time time, leave_time time, chek_total_num_user int);
insert into timeTable values
 ('a1','A','07:44','08:02',1)
,('b2','A','07:45','07:50',2)
,('c3','A','07:49','08:05',3)
,('d4','A','08:03','08:05',2)
;
with t1 as(
select  username,room,start_time as event_time, 1 InOut
from timeTable
union all
select  username,room,leave_time as event_time, -1 InOut
from timeTable
)
select  * 
  ,sum(InOut)over(partition by room order by event_time) total_num_user_at_event
from t1
order by event_time
```

| username | room | event_time | InOut | total_num_user_at_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a1 | A | 07:44:00.0000000 | 1 | 1 |
| b2 | A | 07:45:00.0000000 | 1 | 2 |
| c3 | A | 07:49:00.0000000 | 1 | 3 |
| b2 | A | 07:50:00.0000000 | -1 | 2 |
| a1 | A | 08:02:00.0000000 | -1 | 1 |
| d4 | A | 08:03:00.0000000 | 1 | 2 |
| c3 | A | 08:05:00.0000000 | -1 | 0 |
| d4 | A | 08:05:00.0000000 | -1 | 0 |